# PHP+Mysql: не работают несколько запросов одновременно?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в php не работает такой групповой запрос:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1';
          DELETE from table WHERE id = '1'";
$res = mysql_query($query);
```

В MySQL всё выполняется без проблем.

Так же, если в php выполнить по отдельности, то тоже всё выполняется:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1'";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$query = "DELETE from table WHERE id = '1'";
$res = mysql_query($query);
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Спасибо!

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php): _"mysql_query() посылает один запрос (посылка нескольких запросов не поддерживается)"_. Не ну серьезно, вы вообще справкой пользуетесь иногда?

Comment: Не используйте функции `mysql_*`, они устарели. Посмотрите в сторону мультизапросов http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: @teran Справка? Не, не слышал (С)

Comment: Похоже что автору еще и на транзакции в SQL стоит обратить внимание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из комментариев и документации:

> **mysql_query()** посылает один запрос (посылка нескольких запросов не поддерживается) активной базе данных сервера ... [[1]](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php)

> Не используйте функции **mysql_***, они устарели. Используйте вместо них [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [PDO_MySQL](https://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Answer (score 1):

Напишу, что для расширения `mysql`, если движок БД - `InnoDB`, то можно обернуть всё в одну транзакцию и работать с ней:

```
class MySQLDB
{
   private $connection;          // The MySQL database connection

   /* Class constructor */
   function MySQLDB(){
      /* Make connection to database */
      $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
   }

   /* Transactions functions */

   function begin(){
      $null = mysql_query("START TRANSACTION", $this->connection);
      return mysql_query("BEGIN", $this->connection);
   }

   function commit(){
      return mysql_query("COMMIT", $this->connection);
   }

   function rollback(){
      return mysql_query("ROLLBACK", $this->connection);
   }

   function transaction($q_array){
         $retval = 1;

      $this->begin();

         foreach($q_array as $qa){
            $result = mysql_query($qa['query'], $this->connection);
            if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0){ $retval = 0; }
         }

      if($retval == 0){
         $this->rollback();
         return false;
      }else{
         $this->commit();
         return true;
      }
   }

};

/* Create database connection object */
$database = new MySQLDB;

// then from anywhere else simply put the transaction queries in an array or arrays like this:

   function function(){
      global $database;

      $q = array ( 
         array("query" => "UPDATE table WHERE something = 'something'"),
         array("query" => "UPDATE table WHERE something_else = 'something_else'"),
         array("query" => "DELETE FROM table WHERE something_else2 = 'something_else2'"),
      );

      $database->transaction($q);

   }
```

---

Как уже отмечалось выше:

> Не используйте функции mysql_*, они устарели. Используйте вместо них MySQLi или PDO_MySQL

И как облегчение: у `mysqli` есть как раз-таки функция для **[множественных запросов](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)**. Примитивный пример:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test") || !$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE test(id INT)")) {
    echo "Не удалось создать таблицу: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS _num FROM test; ";
$sql.= "INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1); ";
$sql.= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS _num FROM test; ";

if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
    echo "Не удалось выполнить мультизапрос: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

do {
    if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        $res->free();
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
```

Comment: непонятно, в чем облегчение от наличия функции для множественных запросов. В том что приходится городить вот такой многоэтажный говнокод?

Comment: @Ипатьев иди городи свой идеальный код в свою коморку душноты.